# Motorcycle Electrical issues

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, no-crank-no-start, ducati

I have a 2013 Ducati Monster 696cc that wont start, when I turn the key to the leftmost position the dash does not light up. None of the lights turn on except for one out of four LEDs that are mounted above my license plate. I charged the bike for 6 hours today but only realized that the charger wasn't actually charging (due to the bright light earlier in the day I couldnt actually see if the charging light was on) until later today. Also the bike doesn't turn over or start. Any help would be nice, Thank you.

Comment: *right most* position

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you have something which needs to be modified in your question, just click on the edit button and change the wording.

Answer (score 0):

You can confirm the battery is dead by performing a load test. Try charging it (out of the bike) on a car charger or even with jumper cables to a car (never ever with the battery in the bike) then do a load test.

If your battery is more than 3 years old, the first thing to do is buy a new one and charge it. Sadly, I don't ride as much as I should and my last battery got one ride in during its entire life. Once the battery goes flat long enough, they don't like to come back. I've had a few Yuasa YT12B-BS batteries in Ducatis that sat 6+ months and came back to life, but it's a rare occurrence.

The best procedure I've found for AGM batteries is to fill it and let it sit a few hours (like during the day). Then set the port cover on it without seating it. Then charge the battery overnight before fully installing the cover.